# Get google analytics stats for a user identified by a custom data layer property

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

We have the following scenario:

`Website A` has GTAG installed and tracks every page visit, sending a `internalUserId` along in the `dataLayer` (when the user is logged).

`Website B` is a CRM where we list all users, and it uses the same database as `Website A`.

In the CRM we need to see what pages each of our users have visited.

**Proposed solution**:

1. **Ideal solution**: call Analytics API passing `internalUserId` and returning a list of pages the user visited.
2. **Alternative 1**: make `Website A` call an internal API that registers a visit, along with any other metadata. Unfortunately the dev team behind `Website A` wants to avoid this approach as it will send yet another request on every page, thus slowing the page down.
   So the suggestion was to leverage analytics to gather this information.
3. **Alternative 2**: somehow instruct Tag manager to call an external API every time a visit occurs, and send along any meta data. I don't actually know if Tag manager offers this service or not.

The **alternative 1 & 2** will mean that we will store the visit stats, while the **ideal solution** will use Analytics stats.

So the question is:

**Does Analytics API offer the ability to query for a specific user identified by a custom property, `internalUserId`, that we set using `dataLayer`, and return that user's stats (visits) ?**

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can query Google Analytics API using your `internalUserId` unless you set it as the user ID in GA, which may lead to limitations. You'd be better off merging the data by collecting the `_ga` cookie along with you `internalUserID` values. Look up all user activity by `_ga` and then merge to your CRM data with `internalUserID`.

I don't believe alternative 2 is possible.

Alternative 1 would require you store the data yourself and a client side call, but you'd avoid ongoing GA API usage. The calls from client side could be minimal. Use a Cloudflare worker to fetch and process only the data you need, that could be an interesting solution.